# Solving for a Variable

Tags: c

How would I got about solving for the variable `num`, which would be my own input to the program, in the compare function?

main function (part)

```
int input;
answer = compare(input);

if(answer !=0xb88202) {
   printf("Keep trying!");
   exit(0);
}

puts("You got it");
```

compare function

```
uint compare(uint num) {
     return (num ^ 0x735) >> 4 ^ 0x6f0;
}
```

I'm honestly not sure how to go about this.  I figured somehow reversing the XOR with another XOR would help.  I also tried left shifting `0xb88202` by the `4 ^ 0x6f0` but I just can't figure this out.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? What are the magic numbers?

Comment: `XOR` is its own inverse: `a ^ y ^ y == a`

Comment: So the program is simply taking my input, and either meeting the condition or not.  I don't understand how to evaluate num from the operation to provide the program with the correct input.

Comment: Are you asking what value of `num` results in `(num ^ 0x735) >> 4 ^ 0x6f0` being equal to `0xb88202`?  If so, that's a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence <- this may also be useful (compare `^` vs `>>`)

Comment: Based on your closing comment, you are missing the point of _precedence_. The value is shifted by 4 and then XOR is performed.

Comment: ...which is why when writing code like this I add "unnecessary" parentheses to make it clearer when I or someone else revisits the code a year later.  If I have to think about the order, I add parens so I don't have to later or have a chance of getting it wrong.

Comment: There are actually 16 correct values for the input, since the right shift by 4 throws away the four least significant bits of the input. The four LSBs of the input can be anything from 0x0 to 0xF.

Comment: First step is to understand the precedence -- your comment on what you've tries suggests you do not.  xor (`^`) is lower precedence than shift, so this is `((num ^ 0x735) >> 4) ^ 0x6f0;`

Comment: You can rearrange the formula to `(num >> 4) ^ 0x73 ^ 0x6f0 = 0xb88202`, because the least significant nybble of `num ^ 0x735` is thrown away by the shift. Computing `0x73 ^ 0x6f0` gives `((num >> 4) ^ 0x683) = 0xb88202`. XOR both sides by 0x683 to get `(num >> 4) = 0xb88481`, and therefore `num = 0xb88481z` where `z` is any hex digit.

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the operations in the compare function.

```
input = (0xb88202 ^ 0x6f0) << 4 ^ 0x735
```

Comment: Some discussion of why this works, and why it would not work, or would not work easily, with every `compare` function, would be useful. If the `compare` were `return num * 0x735 >> 4;`, what would you do?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Information is lost during the function you've given. That means it cannot be directly solved algebraically, and thus you'd need to brute-force the answer; but you can make the process more intelligent by looking at the mathematical properties of each constant inside it, and making assumptions about the range of possible values of `num`, and the XOR operations in the `compare` function. So the result will be a combination of the binary representations of num and the constants inside `compare`. If num is large, the result of the XOR and shift operations will be larger as well.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `I didn't give any function, I'm not the OP.` Sorry if that confused you, I meant `return num * 0x735 >> 4;`.

Answer (score 1):

Treat it as an equation and solve.  You have

```
answer == ((num ^ 0x735) >> 4) ^ 0x6f0
```

xor is its own inverse, so you get

```
answer ^ 0x6f0 == (num ^ 0x735) >> 4

(answer ^ 0x6f0) << 4 == (num ^ 0x735)

((answer ^ 0x6f0) << 4) ^ 0x735 == num
```

This isn't quite correct for the shift as a right shift loses bits (shifted off the bottom) that the left shift won't recover, but this just means that there are multiple values of `num` that will give you that `answer` and this finds one of them.